# Source of a Russell quote about difficulties in his work

Tags: bertrand-russell, quote, principia-mathematica

Some years ago I read somewhere a memoir by Bertrand Russell. He wrote about the difficulties he encountered in writing Principia Mathematica (or trying to solve the paradox that bears his name). He wrote something like, "In the morning I sat down at my desk in front of a white sheet of paper, and in the evening I realized that I was still sitting in front of a sheet of paper without a line written on it."

Please help me find the source where I could see this quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See B.Russell's [Autobiography (1975)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Autobiography/uIKMAgAAQBAJ) page 142:

> I was trying hard to solve the contradictions [...]. Every morning I would sit down before a blank sheet of paper. [...] Often when evening came it was still empty. [...] It was clear to me that I could not get on without solving the contradictions, [...] but it seemed quite likely that the whole of the rest of my life might be consumed in looking at that blank sheet of paper.

Comment: That is what I need! Thanks a lot!